# Does python argparse have a solution for this case where we have unknown argument names and need to match them to values?

Tags: python, argparse

I am receiving arguments to my script such that the argument vector available to the script looks like the example below.

`sys.argv = ["the/script/path.py", "--key1='value1'", "--key2='value2'", ... "--keyN='valueN'"]`

I have no way of knowing what the key names will be.  The end goal is to get a JSON map of all the key names to value name.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to have the built in `argparse` library help with this.  I understand that I can just do this manually by splitting the string in the list on equals, and removing the extra quote and dash characters.

As far as I can tell, you can use `argparse` to get unknown arguments, but I'm not seeing a clear way to automatically match the argument by name to the proper value after doing this.  I just get a list of strings similar to the contents of `sys.argv`

Is there a clear method using the `argparse` library to convert the contents of my argument list to a JSON map of arguments to values?

Comment: Obviously you can accept quoted strings like this, and parse them yourself after.  Or even write a custom `Action` class to do.  But the basic philosophy of argparse is to give you, the developer, control over what arguments the you expect and accept (that includes the help, usage and errors mechanism).  If you want to accept anything the user throws at you, don't bother with `argparse`; it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: If the point is to accept arguments that *another* script knows how to handle, you can use the `parse_known_args` method, which will return both a `Namespace` object resulting from the arguments that were known and could be parsed, as well as a list containing all the unrecognized arguments as-is to pass on to other script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use argparse for this, but I also don't see why you would need to unless you need to take additional options or positional arguments. Like @hpaulj said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396100/does-python-argparse-have-a-solution-for-this-case-where-we-have-unknown-argumen#comment110354164_62396100), argparse is meant to define what arguments are valid, so where you're expecting anything, don't bother.

Instead, since the arguments are super consistent, do it manually like you're saying.

BTW, if you need to parse the single-quoted strings, there are libraries that can help with that, like [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html).

(This is assuming you can't control the arguments that the script receives.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) to parse the arguments you do know about, and leave the unknown ones in a list to be passed to a parser that *does* now about them.

```
import argparse

p1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p1.add_argument("--key1")

p2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p2.add_argument("--key2")

args1, others = p1.parse_known_args()
args2 = p.parse_args(others)

print(args1)
print(args2)
```

This produces

```
$ python tmp.py --key1=3 --key2=5
Namespace(key1='3')
Namespace(key2='5')
```